# MVC4 many-to-many dynamic model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, many-to-many, model-binding

Alright. I'm not sure how to explain this correctly, and the title of this question might be wrong. I have a many to many relationship between `Reference` and `Category`:

```
public class Reference
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Reference> References { get; set; }
}
```

On creation of a `Reference` entry the user should be able to add as many categories (in form of a drop down list with all available categories) as needed. Here's what I've come up with so far for the view for the model binder to figure it all out without any logic in the controller to create related data:

```
<div class='meta-container meta-cat'>
    <div class="meta-sub">
          <div class="editor-label">Name</div>
          <select name="Categories[0].Name" value="">
             @{
               var db = new DbContext();
               var categories = db.Categories.ToList();
               foreach (var c in categories)
               {
                    <option value="@c.CategoryId">@c.Name</option>
               }
              }

          </select>
     </div>
</div>
     <div class="additonalContainersCats"></div>
     <input type="submit" value="Add another category" id="AddCat" />

    <script>
            $('#AddCat').click(function () {
                var propNumber = 0;
                var dropdown = $(this).parent().find('select').first();
                var options = "";
                $(dropdown, "option").each(function() {
                    options += $(this).html();
                });
                $('.meta-cat').each(function () {
                    propNumber++;
                });
                var html = "<div class='meta-container meta-cat'>" +
                                "<div class='meta-sub'>" +
                                    "<div class='editor-label'>Name</div>" +
                                    "<select name='Categories[" + propNumber + "].Name' value=''>" +
                                     options +
                                    "</select>" +
                                "</div>" +
                                "</div>" +
                            "</div>";
                $('.additonalContainersCats').append(html);
                return false;
            });
    </script>
```

So everytime the user clicks the Add new category button a new drop down list is created with `name="Category[int].Name"`.
This would work with a one-to-many (one category for a reference) relationship and text boxes instead of drop down lists.
This is not very pretty looking MVC (its very webform'ish) :)

How would you do this?

UPDATE - forgot to mention the result when submitting the data. 
New Categories are created. If I choose 2 categories for the reference, two new categories are created with `Name` property from `CategoryId` of the original categories. Relations are created between the reference and the new categories. Funky huh :)

Comment: why wouldn't this work for many to many? (maybe I don't get something here)

Comment: I tried to do some modifications, take a look: http://jsbin.com/awanur/1/edit

Comment: @FelipeOriani - I see what you did there. But that's not really the issue is it?. And that won't work cause there's some javascript left out of the example to simplify it that wont work with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was very simple. Just had to give the drop down lists name="Category[int].CategoryId" insted of .Name. I then manually loop through the property and binding it. New categories was not created when manually binding.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Default ModelBinder doesn't really know how to map your Categories to existing Categories in the database. This is where you might want to consider implementing either AutoMapper (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) or your own structure to map your new Reference with list of existing Categories - you would just need to iterate over the collection of CategoryIDs you are already sending, retrieve them from the DB and overwrite your Reference.Categories.